# Global variables in the main Java

Tags: java, variables

I have the following problem, and know why this is giving me some problems. I wonder if there is a way to use somehow nmarked in the declaration of the market array?

```
public class Main {
         static final int[] market = new int[nmarked];
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         int nmarked=3;
         }
 }
```

thx a lot!

Comment: since `nmarked` is a local variable in your `main`, no. If you´d make it a class member variable then yes.

Comment: nmarked is local variable of main method and it's scope only within main method.

Comment: please add all the relevant code to the question and emphasise what you try to achieve. it's not very clear now

Answer (score 7):

You can initialize the array inside the main method (it can't be `final` though) :

```
 static int[] market;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int nmarked=3;
     market = new int[nmarked];
 }
```

Comment: sorry but this variable is marked as final and assignation can't be done later in the main method. It wont work.

Comment: @VivekSingh good point. I didn't notice the final declaration. I'll just remove it.

Comment: ooops sorry, right, it was supposed to be like this: 
     static int[] market;

Comment: yes, noticed the mistake. and now this solution, but then I need to pass by reference to other functions and this is not working.

Comment: @AbneryOrtiz What do you need to pass to other methods?

Comment: @AbneryOrtiz And what problems are you encountering when trying to pass it? Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: You can pass it. Making it final wouldn't make it immutable. I mean even if it was final, it would only mean you can't reallocate it, but still could change it's elements

Comment: When I pass the array to the functions, this is empty!

Comment: @AbneryOrtiz Do you mean empty or null? It should contain 0s.

Comment: @AbneryOrtiz Where is the code in which you pass it to other methods? Is it inside the main method or in some static initializer block or static variable initialization that's executed before the main method?

Comment: Gavriel, I use a very simple constructor passing this array.

Comment: @AbneryOrtiz Where are you calling the constructor?

Comment: It is a thread. Is this enough or you need the thread code, as well? 

static int[] market;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int nmarked=3;
     market = new int[nmarked];
 
     Consume_order consume = new Consume_order(int[] market);
     consume.start();
}

Comment: @AbneryOrtiz But where are those statements located? In the main method? In addition, `new Consume_order(int[] market)` won't pass compilation. You don't specify the type of an argument in a method or constructor call.

Comment: please edit the question and add all the relevant code parts. It's hard to read it in the comments

Comment: Also: if you use threads, then you might have some synchronization problems between your threads

Comment: no Gavriel, this was working when I use global variables. The problem is that I need to read this array in Main.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better view of the code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int [] market = new int[3];
     for (int i=0;i<3;i++) market[i]=i;
     Consume_order consume = Consume_order(market);
     consume.start();

 }

 public class Consume_order extends Thread {
   public run(){
      private int[] array;
      public Consume_order(int[] array) {
           this.array=array;
      }
      System.out.println(array[0]);
 }
```

}

Comment: `Consume_order consume = Consume_order(int[] market)` will not pass compilation, and it's not a constructor call. Did you mean `Consume_order consume = new Consume_order(market);`?

Comment: Well, in that case the array you are passing is not null. Perhaps the problem is in your `Consume_order` constructor.

Comment: Eran, I populate the array before, but then when I print the first element in the thread. Get Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: and this is giving me null pointer exception. Know market is pass by value and not reference, but how to fix it, no idea!

Comment: Why is your constructor inside the `run` method? Please post code that passes compilation

Comment: 2 different files, it is not in the same. just for simplicity!

Comment: do not know how to add two different piece of codes! :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100643/discussion-between-abnery-ortiz-and-eran).

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to pass nmarket? You don't need to pass it, use: market.length

Or:

```
public class Market {
         final int[] market;
         public Market(int nmarked) {
             market = new int[nmarked];
         }
}

// from main you can call it:

Market market = new Market(3);
```